# How to autoplay an iframe video in fullscreen with HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, autoplay

I want to autoplay a video from google drive in fullscreen  inside of an `<iframe>` on my website. I have searched far and wide but I was unable to find the anwser to my question. I know that the HTML5 `<video>` tag has an autoplay option but the problem is that I made my website change the source of the video every time the page reloads and I was unable to make the `<video>` tag change it's source. Even if I somehow succeeded to make the `<video>` tag change it's source the video would still not be able to play because I have tried playing the video without changing the tags source and the `<video>` tag didn't load the video. I have tried loading the video with this link:
`https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jsMys7KI7hjqvOE7UcW-IhkEzFpOFNRJ/preview` 
and this link:
`https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1jsMys7KI7hjqvOE7UcW-IhkEzFpOFNRJ`. 
Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: oO I noticed the site starts loading if you add the wuery parameter autoplay=true :D

Comment: Could you please paste the code?

Comment: I just used 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jsMys7KI7hjqvOE7UcW-IhkEzFpOFNRJ/preview?autoplay=true' but it doesnt get you far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this is to embed the videos into the `<video>` tag  locally using `localhost`, there is currently NO way to do this directly from `Google Drive`.

Answer (score 0):

I've used both of these before

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="../../Video/hopeboxteaser.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Or

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="../../Video/hopeboxteaser.mp4"
     webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: pretty sure the problem is not having direct access to the video but embedding it from google

Comment: its probably easier to host it somewhere else

Comment: Youtube and dailymotion give me a copyright claim and other websites have a limited upload quota.